# PHP If/Else Statements Not Hitting All Cases

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this as my syntax, and my issue is that if both `$employee` and `$saleDate` are set the `where` clause is added as expected.  However, if only `$employee` OR `$saleDate` are set, then the `where` clause is never added to the query.

What is the proper way to write this syntax so that the appropriate `where` clauses is added based off the user selection?

```
if (!is_null($employee) && !is_null($saleDate)) {
  if (!empty($employee) && !empty($saleDate)) {
    $sql2 .= " where employee = '$employee' AND saleDate = '$saleDate'";
  }  
}

elseif(!is_null($date)) {
if (!empty($date)) {
    $sql2 .= " where saleDate = '$saleDate'";
  }
}

elseif (!is_null($employee)) {
  $sql2 .= " where employee = '$employee'";
}
```

**EDIT**
My syntax here is working, except for where `employee = ALL` it is somehow missing that (or ignoring that since I thought I accounted for that)

```
$date = $_POST['userSelectedDate'];
$employee = $_POST['empName'];
if (!is_null($employee) && !is_null($saleDate)) {
if (!empty($employee) && !empty($saleDate)) {
if ($employee <> 'All') {
$sql .= " where employee = '$employee' and salesaleDate = '$saleDate'";
}
}
}

if(!is_null($employee)) {
$sql .= " where employee = '$employee'";
}

if(!is_null($saleDate)) {
if (!empty($saleDate)) {
$sql .= " where salesaleDate = '$saleDate'";
}
}
```

Comment: Empty also checks for null, so you can eliminate the !is_null where you're also checking for !empty. Other than that, you might want to double-check the values and try some logging/echoing/debugging along the script path.

Comment: @aynber - I didn't realize that, thank you.  I've done echoing, and I have verified that (for example) ``$date`` is set, but when I do ``echo $sql2`` the ``where`` clause that goes with that value is not added

Comment: Shouldn't `!is_null($date)` and `!empty($date)` really be `!is_null($saleDate)` and `!empty($saleDate)`? It would make much more sense if you checked the variable you're actually using.

Comment: Are you building SQL queries with this string concatenation? Then please be warned that your queries are open for SQL injection

Comment: @NicoHaase - i understand they are open for sql injection.  But this is for a test only.

Comment: What do you mean by "test"? Why not make all software you write secure? Also, what have you tried to debug why some of these cases are not met as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole script can be simplified into the following one:

```
$saleDate = $_POST['userSelectedDate'];
$employee = $_POST['empName'];

$conditions = [];

if (!empty($employee) && strtolower($employee) !== 'all') {
    $conditions[] = "employee='$employee'";
}

if (!empty($saleDate)) {
    $conditions[] = "saleDate='$saleDate'";
}

if (!empty($conditions)) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

BUT, please note that your query is prone to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), so you better use prepared statements.

Comment: Let me test this.  I just realized I need one more check.  I also need to verify that ``$employee != 'All'`` - how would I add that in?

Comment: I think the last sentence says it all : *USE PREPARED STATEMENTS* or expect injections...

Comment: I understand they are open for sql injection.  this is for a test only.

Comment: No matter what criteria is selected the ``where`` clause is not added.

Comment: How do you set `$employee` and `$saleDate` ? Where are they come from?

Comment: See my edit too.. rename `$date` to `$saleDate` and see the check too

Comment: That is still not meeting the ``All`` check.  All other conditions are good.

Comment: Something's wrong there.. are you sure 'All' is sent? maybe the option's value is some other string

Comment: just inspect the element and see what All options holds as value

Comment: if I do ``echo`` it gives me ``All`` if I use ``var_dump()`` it gives me ``string(3) "All"`` -- i'm also ``echo`` the query on screen and it shows ``WHERE employee = 'All'

Comment: didi you put this conditions too? `strtolower($employee) !== 'all'`

Comment: Yes, that condition has been added, but makes no change. --- Correction, it is making a diff, it seems the culprit is coming from the ``$employee if statement``

Comment: Using the ``strtolower()`` as you suggested resolved.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have three variables in there. `$employee`, `$date` and `$salesDate`. I think this is not intentional.

Also, you're checking the content of `$date` twice.

```php
elseif(!is_null($date)) {
   if (!empty($date)) {
```

So I think this is what you want to do:

```php
if (!empty($employee) && !empty($saleDate)) {
  $sql2 .= " where employee = '$employee' AND saleDate = '$saleDate'";
}

elseif(!empty($saleDate)) {
  $sql2 .= " where saleDate = '$saleDate'";

}

elseif (!empty($employee)) {
  $sql2 .= " where employee = '$employee'";
}
```

Comment: if I try this syntax - the where clause is never added.  I've tried all conditions, ``saleDate`` only, ``employee`` only, and both ``saleDate`` and ``employee`` selected

Comment: I really think it's due to the use of ``elseif`` but I don't know a way around it.

Comment: Sorry, aynber was also right, see the updated answer

Comment: The edited syntax gives me an error of ``SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED ';'``

Comment: Have a look at the brackets in your first line -- or see updated answer

Comment: I just realized I need one more check.  I also need to verify that ``$employee != 'All'`` - how would I add that in?